Можно ли в данной ситуации обойти использование any?
В переменной нужно хранить экземпляр класса BaseStructure (структуру данных) и там допустимое любое значение дженерика BaseStructure (в рамках его ограничения, разумеется). Допустимо ли здесь такое использование any или есть более подходящее для этого решение?
    interface IStructure<T extends IStructure<T>>{
        item: IItem;
        class: BaseStructure<T>;
    }

    class BaseStructure<T extends IStructure<T>>{
        // ...
    }

    let structure: IStructure<any>['class'];


T extends IStructure<T> — а это что означает?

@AlexeyTen дженерик, принимающий интерфейс

Я знаю, просто условие очень странное. А так вы сложным образом написали let structure = BaseStructure<any>. Возможно стоит привести более развёрнутый пример и чего же вы пытаетесь добиться.

@AlexeyTen дело в том, что это что-то вроде "абстрактного интерфейса". Он просто задаёт общую структуру и ограничения для "описания типов" структуры. Это сделано, чтобы избежать большого количества дженериков для классов. В будущем у интерфейсов полей будет больше. Суть интерфейсного поля class в том, чтобы в наследниках от IStructure указывали конкретный класс, поскольку в других местах может использоваться индивидуальные поля и методы класса (который наследуется от BaseStructure)
Пример:
interface IStack extends IStructure{
item: IStackItem;
class: Stack;
}

@o_- можно пример, что вы дальше с этим планируете делать? Мне непонятно, как эта конструкция помогает избежать большого количества дженериков в классе...
